# Is there a way for 'bot to human handoff' in dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I created chat and want to add feature of chatting with human.

I guess that I need some backend for managers to chat with clients. Now we have jivochat.com but if it needed for simple integration can use something else.

What platforms alow to connect a human as a interface for human agent?

Answer (score 1):

You can use third party platforms such as Kommunicate, which provides you with a dashboard including live chat where in any point a live agent can take control of the chat.
Or you can create your own, try this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EOAypIKmzyY&ab_channel=TECHWITHSACH